# Jade aka Pug syntax for iteration

Tags: node.js

I am trying to iterate over a variable in jade with `each`.  the variable, in this case is interpolate like so `#{images}`.  The array contains urls for images.

I can do `img(src="#{images[0]}")` and it works fine

I try to use the `each` functions and keep coming up with errors.  This is the latest attempt.

`div
  each image in #{images}
    img(src="#{image}",height="100px",width="100px")`

i have tried without interpolating image.  and a bunch of other stuff.  is there something i am missing with the space or syntax?

`img(src="#{images[0]}",height="100px",width="100px")`

the above works so i know im getting the variable, again this is with jade extensions.  i tried to migrate this little project to pug but that didnt work, but thats another story.

this is last piece in a pretty cool uploader that uses POST from the browser to upload images to an aws bucket while saving the urls in a mongoDB. figuring this out will add an image gallery to view the uploads.

Answer (score 1):

So after much hassle I have figured it out.  This rule should apply to most scenarios when you send an array as a variable from express over into your jade/pug template.

My issue was that I was trying to interpolate my `images` variable within the `each` loop.  You interpolate like this: `#{variable}`.  That will produce the literal version of your variable, but that is not what is needed in an `each` loop.  You just want the name of the variable, not the literal value.

Instead the code that works is ridiculously simple.

## Wrong:

`each image in #{images}
  img(src="#{image}",height="100px",width="100px")`

## Right

`each image in images
  img(src="#{image}",height="100px",width="100px")`

Now the loop is creating a new image with a src from each value in my `var images=[url,url,etc]`

This jade/pug syntax is a bit confusing at first, but seems to be great if you can figure it out.